# Scroll Pane in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scrollbar

Sorry, probably another silly question, but I've got a lot of information to put onto a pane of my RoR application, how do I implement scroll functionality so if the information is more then what should fit within a fixed pane (say 600 px wide by 600 px down), then a scroll option will automatically be available?

Even better if I can monitor the window size, and if there is more text then window then to automatically enable scrolling both vertically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you need is to style your container element. More to do with CSS rather than Rails

```
.some-container{width:600px;height:600px;overflow:auto;}
```